# OSGi/Karaf doesn't find GelfAppender

Tags: logging, osgi, apache-karaf, graylog2

I try to use Apache Karaf with a Gelf Appender to connect to Log4J, but I just get ClassNotFoundException.

I followed the instructions from [Karaf Docs](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/logging-system.html) section "Using your own appenders":

I added a folder `system/org/graylog2/gelfj/1.1.12/` and copied `gelfj-1.1.12.jar`from Maven repo into the folder. I added this line to `etc/startup.properties`:

```
org/graylog2/gelfj/1.1.12/org.graylog2.gelfj-1.1.12.jar=7
org/ops4j/pax/logging/pax-logging-api/1.7.0/pax-logging-api-1.7.0.jar=8
```

*(Second line was already there, I followed the instruction "add the new fragment bundle to the list before the pax-logging-service bundle".)*

I also added to file `etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg`

```
# Root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,out,graylog2,osgi:*
...
log4j.appender.graylog2=org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender
log4j.appender.graylog2.graylogHost=foo.bar.de
log4j.appender.graylog2.facility=myall
log4j.appender.graylog2.Threshold=INFO
```

If I start karaf I just get this exception:

```
/opt/apache-karaf-2.3.11/bin/karaf server
karaf: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graylog2.log.GelfAppender not found by org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service [4]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByClassName(OptionConverter.java:326)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.instantiateByKey(OptionConverter.java:123)
    at org.apache.log4j.PaxLoggingConfigurator.parseAppender(PaxLoggingConfigurator.java:97)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:639)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:504)
    at org.apache.log4j.PaxLoggingConfigurator.doConfigure(PaxLoggingConfigurator.java:72)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggingServiceImpl.updated(PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java:214)
    at org.ops4j.pax.logging.service.internal.PaxLoggingServiceImpl$1ManagedPaxLoggingService.updated(PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java:362)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updateService(ManagedServiceTracker.java:148)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceTracker.java:81)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.provide(ConfigurationManager.java:1436)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1392)
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "graylog2".
```

I also tried this [instructions](http://camelandjava.blogspot.de/2012/05/karaf-and-graylog2-log4j-appenders-in.html) with the same result.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the latest gelfj-1.1.12.jar, I can tell it's already a fragment bundle which will attach to the pax-logging-service bundle. A quick install, and refesh of the pax-logging-service bundle result in a successful installation of it. 
Adding your configuration from above results in a host not found failure.

Therefore as the gelf bundle is already fragment bundle, all it takes is an installation of it via

```
install mvn:org.graylog2/gelfj/1.1.12
```

and a

```
refresh 2
```

or just do a restart of the container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solved the problem. Could you explain, why I need to install the bundle via shell? How can I assure that it will load in a new installation without access to the shell?

Comment: It doesn't require you to install it via shell. If you want to build your own custom distribution, best to follow the instructions on building your own distribution. If you want to just use it in your own application make sure you have this bundle in your feature.xml, the refresh of the service bundle should be done automatically (depending on the version of Karaf).